# Codex: Database Description: meaning of Cardinality

Tags: wpdb

The following post outlines how to word cardinality is commonly used when
dealing with databases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621077/what-is-cardinality-in-databases. However I have not been able to comprehend how this term is used
on the database desciptions page on the codex: [Database_Description - Table:_wp_postmeta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta)

> Keyname   Type    Cardinality Field
>
> PRIMARY   PRIMARY 13  meta_ID
>
> post_id   INDEX   15  post_id
>
> meta_key  INDEX   7   meta_key

What do 13, 15, and 7 mean here. I have no clue as to what the numbers in
the cardinality field refer to on this page. Thanks.

Comment: Best guess someone's done a `show indexes from wp_postdata` on their own database and copied the numbers, not realising they're specific to their own data.

Comment: What @Rup said, that means is about the uniqueness value not a description of the relationship.

Comment: Would be nice if someone fixed this on the documentation page.

Comment: You know you could do it, we are and the contributers to the codex are - AFAIK - all volunteers.